# PyCharm unable to load NoseGAE

Tags: google-app-engine, pycharm, nose, nose-gae

I've created a nose test config in PyCharm. I have NoseGAE installed in the virtualenv where I'm working. Running tests from the terminal with `./env/bin/nosetests --with-gae src/tests` works great. The PyCharm test config, however, yields

```
/Users/bistenes/Code/myproject/env/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/noserunner.py src/tests/
Testing started at 6:31 PM ...

/Users/bistenes/Code/myproject/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py:395: RuntimeWarning: Unable to load plugin nosegae = nosegae:NoseGAE: nose>=0.10.1
  RuntimeWarning)
```

Config is set to Nosetests, "All in folder" `src/tests`. The error happens whether or not `--with-gae` is passed as a param.

The ensuing failures are indicative of NoseGAE not being loaded:

```
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "datastore_v3"
```

Comment: Oh my god... I solved it and then didn't write down the solution and can't remember it. Will post answer once I solve it again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest `pkg_resources` by running `pip install --upgrade setuptools`. Then add the version of `pkg_resources` you want to be using to the front of your path. In PyCharm you can do this by adding an environment variable to the test configuration: `PYTHONPATH=/path/to/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH`.

This is happening because PyCharm, when support for Google App Engine is enabled (under "Languages & Frameworks"), inserts a bunch of GAE SDK directories to the front of the PYTHONPATH. The Python GAE SDK ships with `setuptools-0.6c11`, a version of setuptools from 2009. This has a very old version of `pkg_resources` bundled with it, which doesn't work with newer nose plugins.

Comment: I tried the same. My setuptools version is 20.7.0. Still getting the same error.